# PHPUnit could not open input file

Tags: php, unit-testing, batch-file, phpunit

I've attempted to install PHPUnit on a windows 2008 server with IIS and I've followed the instructions on the PHPUnit site in terms of manually creating a batch file and setting the environment variable however, when I try checking the installation in CMD.exe

```
phpunit --version
```

I'm getting the "Could not open input file: *" error message. However, when I run

```
php phpunit.phar --version
```

it correctly gives me the version number. I need to know what's causing the error incase it's anything i've potentially done during the installation that's caused it. To confirm the directory has been listed within the system path variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh,  if you're installing this on windows you'll get to the part here you have have to enter this command to create the phpunit.cmd

```
echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
```

do yourself a favour, copy it in as I was simply entering something incorrectly.

Comment: Just wanted to add to this - If you've preserved your phpunit's version number, so the filename itself is phpunit-x.y.z.phar, you need to change the above command to reflect the actual name of the phpunit.phar file, that is: echo @php "%~dp0phpunit-x.y.z.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd

Answer (score 19):

Remove the version in the phar filename (ex. from `phpunit-5.4.7.phar` to `phpunit.phar`), then the script should run.

Answer (score 5):

If you created `phpunit.cmd` and it still doesn't work, you should just rename `phpunit-7.0.2.phar` to `phpunit.phar`, because, by default, it refers to a name `phpunit.phar`

Comment: Helps in 90% of same situations :D